# how to run tests as per respective suite in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have created some testcases in Jmeter.

Now I want to run them separately example smoke testcases only.

Is there any way in Jmeter so I can run my JMeter project for a particular group/collection/suite only.

Is Jmeter provide any annotation or containers mechanism from where I can achieve same.

I have written my cases in Jmeter in below assertions

- JSR223 Assertion
- Response Code
- Response Text

Any workaround will be helpful and appreciated in advance

Answer (score 0):

The right way to module your JMeter scripts is to save small script in different JMXs and combined them by calling each or inside a bigger JMX file which uses [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to execute different JMX files

> The include controller is designed to use an external JMX file. To use it, create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan and add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it. Then save the Test Plan. The file is now ready to be included as part of other Test Plans.

Inside JMX you can also use [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) to reduce code duplication

> The Module Controller provides a mechanism for substituting test plan fragments into the current test plan at run-time.

If you want to execute specific test I suggest send specific properties and check the property inside an If Controller .

for example call with property `jmeter -JexcludeTest1=true ...`

And add an [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) before test 1:

```
"${__P(excludeTest1)}" == "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter script, it has [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) feature where you can define which test elements you want to enable/disable during test execution.

```
scenarios:
  modification_example:
    script: tests/jmx/dummy.jmx
    modifications:
      disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
      - Thread Group 1
      enable:  # Names of the tree elements to enable
      - Thread Group 2
```

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) to get started.

---

Another option is putting requests you would like to enable/disable on demand under [If Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) so you could set "run/not run" condition dynamically.